# expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

Im generating an array in php to see if a user gets discount on the products in his cart. My code:

```
public function actionPrices($request, $action)
{
    $cartId =  $request->cookie('cartid');
    $currentCart = Cart::findOrFail($cartId);
    $items = CartItem::where('cart_id','=',$currentCart->id)->get();
    $foo = array();


    $actionFilters = ActionFilter::where('discount_action_id', $action->id)->lists('filter_options_id');
    //if there are no $actionfilters nothing needs an extra check
    if (count($actionFilters) == 0)
    {
        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            for($i = 0; $i  < $item->amount; $i++)
            {
                array_push($foo, $item->ProductSize->product->Priceval);
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            $product = $item->ProductSize->product;
            $filters2 = ProductFilter::where('product_id', '=', $product->id)->lists('filter_option_id');
            $inArray = false;
            foreach ($actionFilters as $f) {


                //CODE CRASHED CHERE
                if (in_array($f, $filters2)) {
                    $inArray = true;
                }
            }
            if ($inArray)
            {
                for($i = 0; $i  < $item->amount; $i++)
                {
                    array_push($foo, $item->ProductSize->product->Priceval);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sort($foo);
    return $foo;
}
```

Hos is it possible it crashes at that spot?

The error suggests argument 2 ($filters2) is not an array. But I get $filters2 with lists() function which returns an [array](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries). from the docs

> > If you would like to retrieve an array containing the values of a single column, you may use the lists method.

How should I avoid the error?

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using? The lists behaviour changed between 5.1 (in your docs) and 5.2.

Comment: @JoelHinz In my composer file I have 
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*", >php artisan --version gives me
Laravel Framework version 5.1.30 (LTS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `Query Bulders's lists` method returns a Collection () Object of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`

So you can do this

```
$filters2 = ProductFilter::where('product_id', '=', $product->id)->lists('filter_option_id')->toArray();
```

i.e. converting the collection to array. Or...

```
if ($filters2->contains($f)) {
   $inArray = true;
}
```

i.e. using method of Collection instead of php array.

See [more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#available-methods)

Edit: Oops! Laravel doc incorrectly mentions: the lists returns an array.

Comment: ->toArray() worked ->contains told me it wan't an object so i couldnt use it,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe $filters2 won't be an array for every case.
Try something quick and dirty like:

```
            //CODE CRASHED CHERE
            if (is_array($filters2) && in_array($f, $filters2)) {
                $inArray = true;
            }
```